# AFNetworking : Re-use Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

We know that we can get return value from a normal method, for example :

```
-(NSString*)ASimpleFunction:(NSString*)str{
    return str;
}
```

Calling this : `[self ASimpleFunction:@"abc"]` will return `"abc"`.

If I have declared it in singleton class, so that I can use it from anywhere like:

```
+(NSString*)ASimpleFunction:(NSString*)str{
    return str;
}
```

Calling it: `[Singleton ASimpleFunction:@"xyz"]` will return `"xyz"`.

Hence above method, declared in Singleton class can be accessed/**Re-used** from anywhere by class name itself i.e. `Singleton`.

Similarly, I want to reuse the AFNetworking Method, I will pass `NSDictionary` of parameters , `NSString` for URL etc. But the thing is AFNetworking's `Success and Failure` blocks don't return values. So , I can't get `reponseObject` on success and `error` on failure in return.

Am I doing it right writing same code i.e, url, parameters, [success..]/[failure..] block again an again for each networking request?

Or is there is a good suggested architecture is available?

**P.S** - I have googled a lot for it but found nothing.

Comment: You have to create your own helper class for it. Your learning will help you in future. Try to search about how to get data from block... etc.

Comment: Its is more a design question.

You can create you own BaseConnection class that would use the AFNetworking.

Then create subclass of the formed class and use methods to create a request and get a completion block from it.

Comment: @AshishKakkad - Right on the spot. I need to learn helpers and Blocks. Few answers below, will try them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create your own helper class and use anywhere you can.

First let's create method to call `AFNetworking` response, success and failure:

```
+(void)getWebserviceWithURL:(NSString*)strUrl withParam:(NSDictionary*)dictParam withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary*response))completion withFailure:(void(^)(NSDictionary*response))failure withLoadingText:(NSString*)text
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

    [manager GET:strUrl parameters:dictParam success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
//        [[Helper sharedInstance] dismissProgressBar];
        completion(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure([NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:error, operation, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"error",@"operation", nil]]);
//        [[Helper sharedInstance] dismissProgressBar];
    }];
}
```

Now you can create your own method and get response, success and failure using the completion block:

```
- (void)WebSeries:(void(^)(bool status, NSMutableArray *seriesResponseData, NSString *compMessage))completion
{
    //NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"data", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iComicBookId", nil]];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"fk_iWebSeriesId"];


    [Helper postWebserviceWithURL:EPISODESURL withParam:dict withCompletion:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        NSMutableArray *webSeriesData = response[@"data"];

        completion(YES, webSeriesData, response[@"msg"]);

    } withFailure:^(NSDictionary *response) {

    } withLoadingText:@"Loading"];
}
```

Hope this helps!